# TypeScript forgets what's the type of my variable when using if blocks in Svelte

Tags: typescript, types, interface, svelte

I have a simple variable which can be of different types:

```js
// Here the generic type
type Element = Text | List | Picture;

enum Types {
  Title = "Title",
  Paragraph = "Paragraph",
  List = "List",
  Picture = "Picture"
}

interface Text {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  type: Types.Title | Types.Paragraph;
}

interface List {
  id: string;
  parentListId: string;
  ordered: boolean;
  items: (Paragraph | List)[];
  type: Types.List;
}

interface Picture {
  id: string;
  description: string;
  blob: Blob;
  type: Types.Picture;
}
```

Using conditions, TypeScript should be able to guess what precise type I'm talking about. Here an example:

```js
function doSomething(generic: Element) {
  if (generic.type === Types.Picture) {
    // here, Visual Studio Code will autocomplete my code
    // with properties unique to the Picture type.
  } else {
    // anything but Picture
  }
}
```

I want the same behaviour when using if blocks in Svelte:

```html
{#each elements as element (element.id)}
  {#if element.type === Types.Picture}
    <!-- here TypeScript understands that the element is not of type Element, but Picture -->
    <SomePicture {element} />
  {:else if element.type === Types.List}
    <SomeList {element} />
  {:else}
    <!-- here TypeScript understands that `element` must be a Text -->
    <SomeText {element} />
  {/if}
{/each}
```

So far everything's good, but the problem comes when I want to give a function as prop to my component:

```html
{#each elements as element (element.id)}
  {#if element.type === Types.Picture}
    <!-- here TypeScript understands that the element is not of type Element, but Picture -->
    {console.log(element)}
    <!-- HOWEVER IN THIS ANONYMOUS FUNCTION TYPESCRIPT DOESN'T UNDERSTAND -->
    <!-- it keeps telling me that `element` is of type `Element` and not `Picture` as above. -->
    <SomePicture on:something={(e) => handlePicture(element, e)} />
  {:else if element.type === Types.List}
    <SomeList {element} />
  {:else}
    <!-- here TypeScript understands that `element` must be a Text -->
    <SomeText {element} />
  {/if}
{/each}
```

Basically, when using conditions on the `type` property, TypeScript is able to understand what the exact type of my variable based on the union defined in `Element`. However, when I want to use my variable in a lambda function, TypeScript forgets its guess and goes back to the generic type (`Element`). It's very annoying because my function `handlePicture` expects a `Picture`, and because we can't write TypeScript in props, I have no choice but to do something that will give my nightmares:

```js
// forced type restriction due to TypeScript's unexplained behaviour...
// my `picture` parameter should be of type `Picture` but I can't.
function handlePicture(picture: Element, e: Event) {
  picture = picture as Picture;
  // ...
}
```

It seems to be specific to Svelte because when I recreated a similar situation within [TypeScript's online playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2AZygbwLACgqwJYAuANsFALxQBEMhJlANNrgAoCGATqwOacIAW5Km049W-BkyjM8AYwJh2pCpWlyFwStgC+2bAUSkAygHsIwAKIkzIAoJNmYwAB62APlHvBV8xQG5dWHg2wOwAZqwyRqbAji7okngAJgBcUMgE7EFc-jhQBM4EqemZINmS+kip8EjIAHQ0xKTu1Si1wty8fDk6WNhB+WERUWbe6vG5SUUZWTm4iSgymQgEeMYgUyVluRXAVQZ1o37aAaFgIHKrIFCJxp4EfFkAFMBWoIUe0ZbA1gQAlOO4PChKDPV42Wo7chkCgtA6yHzAf6YXK4GRrZDGEi1IjGLiPSj3UiQvCoVhQBDw9SUX6SLRQF7IUjI3Co9GY4DY3H4wl5AxQEn0wh8EJQMn5OLGdiivK0DS-WYstEgDFYnF4l7fN7yqAAeh1UD4xgAbiLjSKeUaOHhWAAjEiikCJPLC3lIKAAdzwRCIUBtpEonliBEoIIAwgB5ABKkfMoZgNJRUCVKo5asej3+ZAAfACWazlezOeqwX8FbgtPLacdelhk7ZxQRzE5WBAECRUp4vj9BMz+SkqPl0hJtgY9jU2hwOmI+IxtgVUgHonkClBQpLnaQEJPROJq9gbncHqVHg2my224icn1gSeCmfW1jIdCYfsJyJOkjJMnC2mM+Qc6ezYPpe2hAA) it was working just fine.

Does someone have an idea on how to make TypeScript understand what the type of my variable is in the lambda function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference is in a callback and the element might change between the `{#if}` check and when the event happens, you should run into the same issue with plain TypeScript if not everything is `const`.

You can use a [`@const`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) after the check and reference that instead:

```html
{#if element.type === Types.Picture}
  {@const picture = element}
  <SomePicture on:something={(e) => handlePicture(picture, e)} />
```

Comment: It works! Thank you but I don't know this syntax, what is it? "@const" ??

Comment: Just a way to declare a constant value in the template. E.g. if a longer or expensive expression is used in multiple places, that can be used to store it. ([docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const))